# ng build -prod ERROR from pipe

Tags: angular

I got an

```
ERROR Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

caused from my pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

I call this pipe like

```
<span *ngFor="let property of properties | keys">
```

Does anyone sees the problem? Thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, to answer my own question: Calling the pipe with no argument caused the error. This `args:string[]` expect a string of course. So I rewrite the pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) : any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone help this out.

Comment: Correct, just out of curiosity, why do you need a `pipe` here? you are not using the passed argument `i.e.: key`, which I guess is `undefined`. And by seeing your code, I assume, `properties` is an array of objects which contain many keys, other than `key` or maybe it just contains the key `key`. Whatever the case you can do the transformation of getting the array as `key` `value` pair, before starting the loop. why apply the filter throughout the loop? An if you are actually using the filter and you need the param: `key` then inside your pipe, accept it as `transform(value: <type>,args: any)`

Comment: I use the pipe for nested JSON objects and have to check some keys inside the loop. Anyway, thank you for pointing in this direction.